# SQL : Error Syntax #1064

Tags: mysql, sql, join, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I don't find my error in this query :

```
DELETE FROM T1, T2 WHERE T2.id_user = 2 AND T1.id_cat = 2 AND T2.id_cat = 2
```

If I replace 'DELETE' by 'SELECT *' , I obtain what I want, but when I use DELETE, I've got this Error Syntax #1064.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't delete something if you don't say what it is: `DELETE FROM ...`.

Comment: DId you even read a short summary of DELETE in documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what you want to delete.

```
DELETE T1, T2
    FROM T1, T2
    WHERE T2.id_user = 2 AND T1.id_cat = 2 AND T2.id_cat = 2;
```

This assumes you want to delete rows from both tables.

Comment: This is the first time I see this syntax with the tables noted just after the DELETE and it worked!

thank you very much !!!